# How to serialize a DataTable to a string?

Tags: .net, string, datatable, serialization

Recently I was in the need to serialize a `DataTable` as a string for further processing (storing in a file).

So I asked myself: How to serialize a DataTable into a string?

Comment: -1: Use `XmlWriter.Create` instead of `new XmlTextWriter()`

Comment: @Uwe Keim: Yes, it is okay to post code snippets, but it should still follow the question/answer format of the site.  Your question about serializing a data table is fine, but the code snippet should be posted separately as an *answer*.  That would follow the Q&A guideline, and would also encourage others to post answers of their own.

Comment: Should I change it now, Bill? Or take care of the guideline for the next time I post?

Comment: @Uwe Keirn - I would change the question to read How to serialize a table, and then post your code as one of the answers.  There might be better or more interesting solutions you can learn from.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is the code I wrote to perform the task of serializing a `DataTable` into a string:

```
public static string SerializeTableToString( DataTable table )
{
    if (table == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        using (var tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            // Must set name for serialization to succeed.
            table.TableName = @"MyTable";

            // --

            tw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

            tw.WriteStartDocument();
            tw.WriteStartElement(@"data");

            ((IXmlSerializable)table).WriteXml(tw);

            tw.WriteEndElement();
            tw.WriteEndDocument();

            // --

            tw.Flush();
            tw.Close();
            sw.Flush();

            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is useful for someone somewhere out there.

*(Please note that I [asked in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22706) whether it is OK to post snippets and got replies that this should be OK; correct me if I am wrong on that - thanks!)*

Comment: Why not just shove it in a DataSet, and save that? Should be no more than 2-3 lines...

Comment: This was, what I tried first. To my surprise, the DataSet reference of the DataTable was NULL, so I used this solution.

Comment: What would be the reverse of this? When I try to read the xml back into a DataTable I get a "There is an error in XML document (0, 0)" error when calling this:

                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataTable));
                FileStream file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
                DataTable retval = (DataTable)serializer.Deserialize(file);
                return retval;

Answer (score 9):

You can also try writing out the DataTable to XML which works just as nicely:

```
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim DataTableAsXMLString As String
'...code to populate DataTable
Using sw As New StringWriter()       
    dt.WriteXml(sw)
    DataTableAsXMLString = sw.ToString()
End Using
```

...then if needed you can convert the XML right back to a DataTable:

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt2 As DataTable
Using sr As New StringReader(DataTableAsXMLString)
    ds.ReadXml(sr)
    dt2 = ds.Tables(0)
End Using
```

Comment: Make sure you also give the datatable a name (`dt.tableName = "MyDataTable"`) before you call dt.WriteXml(sw) otherwise you'll get an exception.

Comment: Code is wrong. `dt.WriteXml(sw)` does not return a string. You need to call `dt.WriteXml(sw)`, then `DataTableAsXMLString = sw.ToString()`

Comment: I modified the answer to wrap disposable items in a using block otherwise you might see your memory usage climbing at an alarming rate

Comment: Also fixed the answer as per @nunzabar comments

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable()  
//... Fill Datatable from SQL or a thousand other places you have seen on the net.     
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";    
dt.WriteXml(Response.OutputStream);  
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Documentation found at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.writexml(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest NOT to serialize the DataTable and use custom entities for persistence/contracts to avoid [difference in implementation details between .Net versions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914460). The XML schema of the DataTable class is undocumented implementation detail that you should not rely on.