# How to upload a DataTable to Azure Blob Storage using C#?

Tags: c#, azure, datatable, blob

I have a DataTable with about 500 rows in C# which I want to upload to Azure Blob. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason you do not want to store this in a db table ?

Comment: Yes, it's a client requirement.

Comment: Not sure what the exact question is, but as written, this is fairly broad. Are you asking for specifics on writing content to blobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could consider serializing the DataTable first and then uploading the serialized data to blob storage?

[How to serialize a DataTable to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244655/how-to-serialize-a-datatable-to-a-string)